# Derogatory word or idiom for city dwellers or people who aren't adapted to country/rural life

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, pejorative-language

I'm looking for something people from rural area would use, especially when they refer to that person's inability to adapt to the country life.

Comment: These expressions will vary widely by location; if you're interested in a particular locale, it would be good to mention it.

Comment: Rural Catalans sometimes refer to Barcelonins as 'pixapins' (pronounced 'pishapins') which literally means 'pine-pissers' - people who urinate on pine trees.  Presumably country folk are more discreet.  (The term 'cagahorts' (pr. 'caga-orts', meaning 'garden-shitter') was supposedly coined in response.)  Another term is 'camaco' (pr. 'camacu'), derived from the expression most uttered by pixapins when they visit the country: 'que maco!' ('how pretty!').

Comment: The term *city dwellers* itself isn't entirely positive, and with the right intonation (and context) can be quite derogatory itself.

Answer (score 57):

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_slicker):

> ### City slicker
>
> ***City slicker*** is an idiomatic expression for someone **accustomed to a city or urban lifestyle and unsuited to life in the country**. The term was typically **used as a term of derision by rural Americans** who regarded them with amusement.

[image: Promotional poster for the movie *City Slickers*, depicting three men in business suits mounted on horses sporting Western-style tack. Billy Crystal is riding his horse backwards, which allows us to see the "I ❤️ NY" bumper sticker on its rump.]

Comment: See also "Dandy" and "Dude" which had a similar meaning.

Comment: @MaxWilliams If you like *dude*, you should upvote [Elian's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/320074/55623), where he suggests that word (I already upvoted him, but someone downvoted, so his answer's net score is currently 0). You might even consider offering an answer of your own, suggesting *dandy*.

Comment: Oh, i didn't see that, sorry.

Comment: I think that on it's own "dandy" is more deserving of a comment than a full answer.  Also I don't think "dandy" is a good answer to the question as it's very outdated now, i just wanted to tack it on to "city slicker" as i think it's in the same ballpark.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Fair enough. Thanks for upvoting Elian's answer btw, I don't think it's gotten enough attention from the community.

Comment: Related: city boy.

Comment: Once again I win "guess the top-rated answer from the title of the question"!

Comment: I agree that City Slicker is the canonical right answer (because it's popular and derogatory), but I want to mention what might be the original answer: "town mouse".  As one of Aesop's fables, it's about 2500 years old.  However, it's less derogatory: the moral of "Town Mouse and Country Mouse" is something like "to each his own" or "there's no accounting for taste".  Town Mouse is unhappy in the country, and Country Mouse is unhappy in town.

Answer (score 17):

[Townie](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/townie) is the obvious answer, but *tourist* or *tripper* often carry overtones of scorn and 'urban, squat and full of guile'. (I knew a young girl who, left in a car for half an hour, hid under the seat because she was afraid of the trippers.)

Comment: Round here (rural Wales) we call them 'townies' and it isn't a compliment.

Comment: Although Merriam-Webster gives it second, the definition of townie that comes to my mind first is *"a person who lives in a town that has a college or university but does not work at or attend the school"*

Comment: None of these sound the slightest but derogatory to me.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: possibly because your home isn't in an area full of tourists.

Comment: I live in a very tourist laden area, and calling someone a tourist is a absolute insult. It implies a general lack of knowledge, a certain amount of carelessness, and a fair bit of rudeness.  Tripper, I have never heard before. Townie, to me, is someone "living" in a town that is not part of the larger social gathering. University students calling the towns established citizens "townies" is the most popular example.

Comment: @TimLymington I'm sure it is, but I'm just providing feedback for the OP that your answer isn't universal and might not be applicable.

Comment: @coteyr the college/university residence meaning is what the word invokes for me as well.

Comment: My experience with the word "townie" is the exact opposite. People from larger/more urban areas spending time in small towns (vacations, some colleges, etc.) call the locals "townies". I have seen this many times and in many places.

Answer (score 15):

I'd suggest,

[[***city***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=555&bih=364&tbm=bks&q=%22them+city+dudes%22&oq=%22them+city+dudes%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...92384.94566.0.95077.5.5.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..5.0.0.NYpBqC25lzE)] [***dude***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22tenderfoot%22+%22city+slicker%22&biw=596&bih=391&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB1qqKnZbMAhUGExoKHfeYAEo4ChD8BQgHKAA&dpr=2#q=%22dude%22+%22greenhorn%22+%22tenderfoot%22+%22pied+tendre%22)

> dude
>
> (*hist.* & *dial.*) a city dweller unfamiliar with life on the range; especially :  an Easterner in the West
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dude)
>
> dude: a person who tries to dress like and talk like a cowboy, but really is a city person.
>
> [Transparent Language](http://blogs.transparent.com/english/howdy-partner-and-other-cowboy-vocabulary/)
>
> *They appeared to be dudes. Tenderfoots from back east. In the clear mountain air we could smell the new leather boots and scabbards holding their shiny new rifles.*
>
> [Montana Misadventures](https://books.google.fr/books?id=cSQjVC-dT30C&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22dudes%22+%22tenderfoots%22&source=bl&ots=voCIPrNhzU&sig=JmNdD-EVGVT6se1HmC4qr9HGbes&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio1N-MgJjMAhVE2CwKHUoNBlsQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22dudes%22%20%22tenderfoots%22&f=false)

[***tenderfoot***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=lucky+luke+%22tenderfoot%22&biw=536&bih=352&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR_ZSYnpbMAhWKDSwKHX17ATMQ_AUICCgB&dpr=2)

> : A tenderfoot is slang for an inexperienced person, **particularly one who is not adapted to a rural or outdoor lifestyle** (emphasis is mine.)
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenderfoot)
>
> *"I'm one of those tenderfoots, you know, can't tell the difference between a coyote and wolf. Might not know the difference if I saw them, either."*
>
> [The Shooter](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22those+tenderfoots%22&biw=323&bih=211&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjltvGHpJbMAhXFkiwKHZ10BjIQ_AUICygG&dpr=2)

***greenhorn***

> a newcomer (as in a country) unacquainted with local manners and customs.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greenhorn)

***fudgie***

> A tourist to the northern lower, or eastern upper peninsula of Michigan, especially the Mackinac area. Often these tourists are from lower parts of Michigan, and are usually on vacation "up north". The name fudgie comes from the fact that many of these tourist like to spend lots of time in the many fudge shops in northern Michigan. Locals are generally not fond of fudgies, as they seem to have no small town driving abilities, and can sometimes be snobby or annoying. fudgies are identifiable by bright clothes, and the presence of cameras around their necks and the use of fanny packs. also, the use of shoes and sock at wholly inappropriate times, such as on the beach and the pronunciation "Mack-in-ack" are dead giveaways.
>
> *You don't have to use your blinker there! what the hell is he doing?*
>
> *Calm down, it's just another fudgie.*
>
> [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fudgie&defid=5078450)

[***cheechako***](http://www.waywordradio.org/discussion/topics/fudgies-flatlanders-and-leaf-peepers/)

> A newcomer to Alaska, ignorant of the terrain, the weather, the animals, the culture, the necessary driving skills in the winter, etc. Opposite of a *sourdough*.
>
> [Urban Dictionary](http://fr.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheechako)

***[city] slick***

> slick
>
> (*n.*) A term of address, generally applied to strangers, implying that the person addressed is slick in the sense of "sophisticated," but often used sarcastically.
>
> (*adj.*) appearing expensive or sophisticated.
>
> [Lexic.us](http://www.lexic.us/definition-of/slick)

***drugstore cowboy***

> A person who dresses and acts like a cowboy but who has never worked as one and has none of a cowboy's skills or experience. Originally a reference to extras in Hollywood western films (who would remain in costume off set), it later extended to anyone who wears cowboy clothing purely for the purposes of style or affectation. Primarily heard in US, South Africa.
>
> [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drugstore+cowboy)
>
> *The senator accused his challenger of being a drugstore cowboy—a city slicker who had no idea what it meant to live or work in the rural countryside.*

[**Ngram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=greenhorn%2Ctenderfoot&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreenhorn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctenderfoot%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: i would be surprised if you've heard "dude" used in this way within the past several decades.

Comment: @sgroves, dude ranches would refer to that meaning I'd imagine.

Answer (score 9):

You might call the person a [yuppie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuppie):

> A yuppie (/ˈjʌpi/; short for "young urban professional" or "young upwardly-mobile professional") is defined by one source as being "a young college-educated adult who has a job that pays a lot of money and who lives and works in or near a large city".

Comment: Nobody talks about yuppies anymore.  Nowadays it's _hipsters_ people complain about!

Comment: I complained about hipsters before it was cool.

Comment: But both yuppie and hipster are specific to small subsets of urban dwellers, e.g. yuppie implies young and professional, leaving out all the older and blue-collar urbanites.

Answer (score 7):

(D**ned) urbanites.  Or if the rural area happens to be hilly or mountainous, flatlanders.

Comment: I love *flatlanders*, +1. Never heard of it until my adulthood, speaking with a native Vermonter.

Comment: I can not figure out what has been "bleeped" out. Go ahead, be rude, it's needed for the greater understanding.

Comment: I've heard the abbreviated "urb" used as a pejorative, although I'm not sure whether it was directed specifically at urbanity or just at a particular subculture therein, since I seem to recall it was used for skater-esque folk.

Comment: // , The "D**ned" means "Damned".

Comment: "Flatlanders" doesn't work if the city they're from is e.g. San Francisco...

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman: I dunno... the few times I've driven through, it seemed pretty flat to me.  A few localized bumps, but there's nothing more than a few hundred feet above sea level.

Comment: @jamesqf - It's not the total elevation so much as the sudden changes from one block to the next.  SF is notorious for having some of the steepest hills you'll find in a major urban area, provided you get off the main streets a bit.  (If you just want elevation, maybe try Denver).  Either way, I'd say most mid western farm country is *much* flatter than some of our major cities...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, San Francisco is flat.  You don't get alpenglow.  It gets dark less than three hours after the Sun goes down.  The terrain doesn't give you a preferred direction of travel.  You don't need to worry about air pressure collapsing your water bottle as you walk back home.  "Snow line" is a foreign concept.

Comment: @Mark - I think you're confusing "flat" with "low altitude".  Look at Lombard Street and tell me the terrain doesn't have an affect on direction of travel.  Florida is flat.  San Francisco is lumpy, just at a low elevation.

Comment: People in northern Michigan (mostly rural) also call people from southern michigan (mostly urban and suburban) flatlanders as well.

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman: You know, I don't remember ever claiming that English is strictly logical :-)  To go in the other direction, not every person from rural areas has a permanently sunburned neck from doing fieldwork, but 'redneck' gets used for them regardless.

Answer (score 5):

Kind of an obscure one, and I don't believe it's an official word, so the only definition available might be urban dictionary, but I have heard it used before. From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cidiot):

> **cidiot**
>
> Noun, adjective. Derived from City+idiot. Someone from the city who's utterly crippled by an inability to survive outside city limits or comprehend any merit or logic in rural life or people.

Comment: I added a link to the source of your definition and identified that source. Please include such citations when you include quotations from other sources in your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Toonser

In the North East of Scotland at least.  I don't think I've ever heard of it used in anything other than a derogatory manner.

> *Awa an wash yersel, ya toonser mink.*
>
> Away and wash yourself you dirty town dweller.

http://www.doricdictionary.com/toonser-noun-urbanite/

Answer (score 2):

In Cornwall, UK they are often referred to as *[grockles](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-grockle)*, though this refers more to 'tourists' than specifically town dwellers (after all, there *are* some towns in Cornwall...)

Answer (score 0):

Another long shot, since the best picks are already taken, but '**burger'**, in its original meaning could be used in derogatory sense. This kind of use originated from XIX century Russian literature, so is more likely to be recognized in countries whose history has been influenced by Russia than others.

Answer (score 0):

**city boy/girl** (disparaging when used to describe an adult)

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/city-boy)

> A boy or man who is a native or inhabitant of a city, or who has urban tastes or manners.