# A slang word for "urban"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be an antonym of "hillbilly" and "redneck"?

E.g. what slang word could replace "urban" in this context?

Why would an urban/city-dwelling guy be interested in agricultural techniques?

Comment: Did you check the Urban Dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I did. Um... should I go into how the way search works on dictionary sites is designed for locating definitions for a specified term but not conducive to the other way around, namely zooming in on the term with a definition in mind (which I assume is the reason there is a single-word-requests tag on this site)?

Comment: um, I think Hot Licks is suggesting the 'urban' dictionary to find a synonym for 'urban'.  Looks like there's a missing emoticon ;-) after the question mark.

Comment: The following questions may not be "identical" but the answers are. Sigh....[Derogatory term for people from places like San Francisco](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405197/derogatory-term-for-people-from-places-like-san-francisco) and [Derogatory word or idiom for city dwellers or people who aren't adapted to country/rural life](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320064/derogatory-word-or-idiom-for-city-dwellers-or-people-who-arent-adapted-to-count)

Comment: Avoid asking for items, ideas, or opinions. Subjective questions will be closed unless the request is expert-level, unique, particularly interesting and thought-provoking, shows substantial effort and research, and demands responses that meet these same standards. See: “[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: @MetaEd I am befuddled by your comment and mod action, because your comment seems to suggest the question is subjective, while the reason you listed for putting the question on-hold says I didn't include enough research. However, Mari-Lou A referenced two other questions on this site that are highly similar to mine in content and format. Those questions don't have any more research than mine, but are not marked "off-topic." I'd take "duplicate", but to say mine is "off-topic" is basically saying, "Others can ask this question, but you can't."

Comment: @EricMlyn The connection is that there is a research requirement even for good subjective questions, as noted in my comment.

Comment: @EricMlyn Avoid the (natural) temptation to make generalizations about site policy based on content you've found on the site. SE sites are curated by users and volunteer mods as time permits. The same rules apply to everyone, but the attention actually paid to individual posts varies from day to day, and the way that volunteers understand and handle each situation varies also. So all curation is necessarily a work in progress. I've found the best sources for SE policy are the [help] pages, the FAQ tag on our meta site and the main meta site, and the SE blog.

Comment: @MetaEd But how is it a subjective question? That seems to me the bottom line. Are all single word requests subjective questions? I am also curious why the community feedback is not weighed up. The message I received from the SE community here, in a nutshell, has been: joke, answer, answer, answer, answer, answer, oh your question might have been answered here and here. Like you I also fine help center pages very helpful. Let's chant [this line](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) together: "At Stack Exchange, we believe moderation starts with the community itself"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could call the *urban/city-dwelling guy* a *city slicker*.

> **City slicker** is an idiomatic expression for someone accustomed to a city or urban lifestyle and unsuited to life in the country. The term was typically used as a term of derision by rural Americans who regarded them with amusement.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_slicker)

(Note that 'guy' is subsumed in the term: you wouldn't call him a 'city slicker *guy*' just as you wouldn't call someone a 'hillbilly *guy*'.)

Answer (score 13):

**townie**

> informal
>   noun
>   derogatory
>   a person who lives in a town (used especially with reference to their supposed lack of familiarity with rural affairs).

"townie": [Google online dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+townie&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=define+townie&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3921j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: This is an extrodinarily different use of the word then I have ever heard. In my experience, "townie" has always been a slur used by college students (or sometimes travellers) to refer to locals. Generally, it suggests that the local is unsophisticated or leading an unfulfilling life.

Comment: @Geoffrey No probs with this usage in Australia (country: ~95% rural; population: ~95% urban).  Farmers especially call the urbanites 'townies'.

Comment: It's not so different. It's derogatory in exactly the same way. It implies that the townie's daily concerns are unrelated to the speaker's, and that somehow makes them inferior. The rural folk just aren't able to use it in as condescending a manner as college students.

Comment: Haha, good point. Here's an urban dictionary link to the term. Definitions 2 and 4 (especially 4) are the only ones that sound approximately correct to my ear. But I guess it is because I'm a youngish American. https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=townie

Comment: This is actually the perfect word, city slicker would be really weird to say, but this suits well. +1

Comment: To me, a city slicker is a townie who got lost. He's out in the sticks.

Answer (score 0):

**Jackeen**

Although that might just be in Ireland...

Comment: Derived from "Jack" as in "Union Jack" and seeing Dublin as being more influenced by British culture than the rest of the island. It doesn't really translate to other cultures, and in Ireland doesn't normally apply to the city folk who live in Cork or Galway or even in Belfast (despite its continuing to be a UK city, and it having a greater per-capita number of the jacks from which the term comes than anywhere in Britain).

Comment: American here; I've never heard this word and if I did hear someone referred to as a "Jackeen" I would assume it to be like "jackass" or something.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a non-answer, but it's too long for a comment and I'm hoping it will lead you down a better path.

I think you're looking at this wrong. You want something analogous for an urban dweller where `?? is to urban as redneck is to rural`. I think this is too broad of a definition. Rednecks/hillbillies are defined by personality traits and interests, not location. There may be a higher concentration of rednecks in rural areas, but they can also live in cities, while non-rednecks can live in rural areas.

So what else defines your city dwelling guy? Is he a banker, or a millenial? Maybe a crackhead. Could he be a professional wrestler, electrician, programmer, or city bus driver?

The point is there's something that defines your guy as someone who "shouldn't" be interested in agricultural techniques, but it's not the fact that he's from the city.